# Converting Pagination from Boostrap 3 to 4

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to create a table that has pagination but i don't understand why the page numbers are not looking how they should.The thing is that with bootstrap 3 this example works.

The code is here: https://www.codeply.com/go/uCOImMmlT2
I get no errors in console but i guess i'm doing something wrong with the classes:( I've tried to read the documentation and i think i'm doing the same thing.

I get this[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

Comment: You are using class `.page_link` instead of `.page-link`.

Comment: you can follow this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/

Comment: Oh i don't know how i missed that :( Thanks for helping!